# Is it possible to split the output of a query into a separate column for each month?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm relatively new to the world of MySql and completely new to Stack Overflow so apologies if this is an easy question to answer but I cannot seem to work it out.
If you have a query that works out a calculation and groups the answer by month, instead of having the answers grouped by month in one column, can you instead split out the groups into a separate column for each month?

I have a table that records every time a vehicle is dispatched for a job.  More than one vehicle can be dispatched for each job. I want to work out the average amount of vehicles dispatched for each job, by location, per month.

My table is called dispatch_log and has the following columns "dispatch_id", "job_id", "location_id", "dispatch_datetime"

The query I'm using to work out average amount of vehicles dispatched per job, by location, per month is:

```
SELECT location_id
      ,CONCAT( YEAR(dispatch_datetime), ' ',MONTH(dispatch_datetime) ) AS month_year
      ,COUNT(job_id)/COUNT(DISTINCT dispatch_id) AS avg_disp_vehicles
FROM dispatch_log
GROUP BY location_id, month_year 
ORDER BY month_year;
;
```

I would really appreciate some guidance please!

Comment: I think it is technically possible to split by month into separate columns, but most likely you would have 12 columns for every entry, all of which are blank except 1.  It isn't a typical situation to try and split up data from 1 column and put it into other columns so it would require some manipulation of the rules.  How are you interfacing to the database?  Can you elaborate on what result you want?  For instance, are you looking for a 12 x N grid of dispatch_id, job_id, location_id or a combination of these values.

Comment: please post an example of expected output

Comment: My original comment states it is probably technically possible.  Let me condition this with, when you are looking for kind of violates the inherit concept of what a 'row' is in a relational database, namely, a set of data which is related to a specific set of table rows linked together by way of your query.  To get your desired result using only SQL and no additional layer (like a .Net front end), it would take a lot of manipulation and the result probably would be terrible to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a PIVOT on months.

There's no PIVOT function in MySQL. Fortunately, since you want to pivot on the months, your number of columns is always fixed to 12 and it's not a hard task to code them all in a query.
If your plan is to have a column for each year/month, you can do that too  but you'll have to hardcode all years/months combinations, and it is probably bad design

It's better to stick on the months only for the columns and have different rows per year.

You should thus do something like this

```
SELECT location_id
      , YEAR(dispatch_datetime)  
      ,(COUNT(job_id)/COUNT(DISTINCT dispatch_id) ) AS AvgTotal
      ,(COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dispatch_datetime) = 1 THEN job_id END) /COUNT(DISTINCT dispatch_id) ) AS AvgJan
      ,(COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dispatch_datetime) = 2 THEN job_id END) /COUNT(DISTINCT dispatch_id) ) AS AvgFeb
      ,(COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dispatch_datetime) = 3 THEN job_id END) /COUNT(DISTINCT dispatch_id) ) AS AvgMar
      ,(COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dispatch_datetime) = 4 THEN job_id END) /COUNT(DISTINCT dispatch_id) ) AS AvgApr
      ,(COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dispatch_datetime) = 5 THEN job_id END) /COUNT(DISTINCT dispatch_id) ) AS AvgMay
      ,(COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dispatch_datetime) = 6 THEN job_id END) /COUNT(DISTINCT dispatch_id) ) AS AvgJun
      ,(COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dispatch_datetime) = 7 THEN job_id END) /COUNT(DISTINCT dispatch_id) ) AS AvgJul
      ,(COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dispatch_datetime) = 8 THEN job_id END) /COUNT(DISTINCT dispatch_id) ) AS AvgAug
      ,(COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dispatch_datetime) = 9 THEN job_id END) /COUNT(DISTINCT dispatch_id) ) AS AvgSep
      ,(COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dispatch_datetime) = 10 THEN job_id END)/COUNT(DISTINCT dispatch_id) ) AS AvgOct
      ,(COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dispatch_datetime) = 11 THEN job_id END)/COUNT(DISTINCT dispatch_id) ) AS AvgNov
      ,(COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dispatch_datetime) = 12 THEN job_id END)/COUNT(DISTINCT dispatch_id) ) AS AvgDec  
FROM dispatch_log
GROUP BY location_id, YEAR(dispatch_datetime)  
ORDER BY YEAR(dispatch_datetime) ;
;
```

I can't test as you did not posted a data sample but it should achieve what you want after some tweaking

Comment: Hi Thomas G.  You are right a PIVOT is exactly what I was after.  Your code almost worked but I slightly extended the logic you showed me.  I inserted the CASE statement after the "/" as well as before.  So for example, for each month I did the following:

Comment: COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(dispatch_datetime) = '01' THEN job_id END) 
/COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MONTH(dispatch_datetime) = '01' THEN dispatch_id  END) AS AvgJan

Comment: Thank you very much for you help Thomas G, I have so many uses for this snippet of code you have shown me.  I have learned nearly everything I know about MySQL from Stackoverflow including the basics like the difference between an INNER JOIN and a LEFT JOIN.  So it was nice to finally get to ask a question for myself and be given an excellent answer which I can use again and again!